# Relative Path in the executing assembly

Tags: c#

I am working on Unit tests that test a method in an application that produces a file. So I decided to put an expected file in a directory called Resource/Empower/.
The resource folder is at the same level as the bin folder of the Unit Test project.

Now what I want to do is get the path of the file name. I cannot hard code because I don't know exactly about the drives on the build server.

So how do I get the relative path of the file. Lets say if the file Name is `expectedMasterFileSetUp.txt`?

I want the path `Resource/Empower/ExpectedMasterFileSetUp.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Why use a URI?

```
string AbsolutePathRelativeToEntryPointLocation( string relativePath )
{
  Assembly entryPoint    = Assembly.GetEntryAssembly() ;
  string   basePath      = Path.GetDirectoryName( entryPoint.Location ) ;
  string   combinedPath  = Path.Combine( basePath , relativePath )      ;
  string   canonicalPath = Path.GetFullPath( combinedPath ) ;

  return canonicalPath ;
}
```

Comment: What is the point of GetFullPath here?  Doesn't Path.Combine already return the full path, or is this to auto-expand things like '..'?

Answer (score 1):

Use Path.GetDirectoryName() on the result of 
`new Uri(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().CodeBase).AbsolutePath`
then Path.Combine() your relative path onto the end.